# Como executar um arquivo flash(.swf) em uma página ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, flash

Tenho uma aplicação ASP.NET WebForms e quero saber como executar um arquivo flash(.swf), em uma div de uma página ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funcionou da seguinte forma:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
        id="painelv3" width="100%" height="100%"
        codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">
        <param name="movie" value="meuArquivoFlash.swf" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
        <param name="FlashVars" value="<% =flashvar %>" />
        <embed src="<% =sUrl %>" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff"
            width="800" height="800" name="meuArquivoFlash" align="middle"
            play="true"
            loop="false"
            quality="high"
            allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"
            type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
            pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
        </embed>
    </object>
```

No code-behind da página aspx declarei as variáveis flashvar (parametros passados para o arquivo swf) e sUrl (caminho do arquivo).

```
    public string sUrl = "";
    public string flashvar = "";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            sUrl = "meuArquivoFlash.swf";
            flashvar = "cdUsuario=1&cdDestino=2";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa definir um HTML object tag em sua página que referencie seu arquivo swf.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp

Segue um exemplo:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668846/how-to-embed-a-flash-swf-file-into-asp-net

Comment: Luis, bem vindo ao StackOverflow! Agradecemos você querer ajudar! No entanto, a sua resposta se resume a um conjunto de links que neste momento são válidos mas nada nos garante que continuem a sê-lo no futuro. O stackOverflow deve ser encarado como um repositório de conhecimento e não apenas um *site* de pergunta e resposta. Ao responder devemos pensar, não só em quem perguntou, mas também em todos aqueles que no futuro poderão usufruir da nossa resposta.